# Adding values to binary string

Tags: python, string, binary, append

I would like to add hexvalues to a binary string so that I end up with a binary string that can be transmitted.
What I want is:
`StringToAppend = "5ce7e615ff0000000000010202041f0140009e005d006404084c5ce82215ff1d02000000010202041f013b0097005c005e04777c"` (I have this in unhexlified form and want to append it to a string a la `StatusStr = chr(0)`
How do I do this??? This is what i have:

```
>>> not_macs_buffer=     unhexlify("5ce7e615ff0000000000010202041f0140009e005d006404084c5ce82215ff1d02000000010202041    f013b0097005c005e04777c")
>>> StatusStr = chr(0)
>>> for i in xrange(0,len(not_macs_buffer)):
...     StatusStr +=chr(not_macs_buffer[i])
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
>>>
```

Comment: It isn't very clear here what you want to do. Perhaps a smaller example with a step by step bit of code would work better...

Comment: are you sure that's your example code?  I get: `TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found` when I try to run `binascii.unhexlify` -- Probably due to the whitespace in there ...

Comment: Also, am I missing here or do you just want `StatusStr = chr(0) + unhexlify(...)`?

Comment: mgilson - no, i need to string in binary form i.e. "unhexlified"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Thanks all but what I actually ended up doing to get what I wanted, is:

```
>>> not_macs_buffer=         unhexlify("5ce7e615ff0000000000010202041f0140009e005d006404084c5ce82215ff1d02000000010202041      f013b0097005c005e04777c")
>>> StatusStr = chr(0)
>>> for i in xrange(0,len(not_macs_buffer)):
...     StatusStr +=chr(ord(not_macs_buffer[i]))
```

Comment: Just so you know, "chr(ord(not_macs_buffer[i]))" can be replaced with just "not_macs_buffer[i]". You're converting a character in a string to an integer and back to a string, which is redundant.

Comment: no, that what confused me as well, it gives me an "an integer is required" - error - must be something with unicode or utf-8 or so I assumed...?

Answer (score 1):

What are you transmitting the string to/from? Does it have to be in hex?

The issue seems to be that are you are converting your hex string into a binary string, then in your loop you are attempting to convert a string character into a character, using chr(). This fails because chr() only takes an integer value representing a 256-value ASCII code, not a string.

To fix your problem, just change `StatusStr +=chr(not_macs_buffer[i])` to this:

```
StatusStr += not_macs_buffer[i]
```

Of course, you could forgo the loop completely.

```
StatusStr = chr(0) + not_macs_buffer
```

And if you really did need to convert a list of integers to a string, you could use a list comprehension and then join the list. (I won't give an example since it's not relevant)

**EDIT:**

If you want to add the null value to your original hex string, you can do this:

```
StringToAppend = '5ce7e6' # ... snip the real value
StatusStr = hexlify(chr(0)) + StringToAppend 
# or
StatusStr = hexlify('\x00') + StringToAppend 
# or
StatusStr = '0000' + StringToAppend
```

Comment: No, I actually want to compile a binary strong like: "000b13AB" = list of values like 0x00 0x0b 0x13 0xab

Comment: I think you need to be clear on your terminology. Python stores binary values in a string using escape characters, like so: "\x00\x0B\x13\xAB". What you have listed is a string containing hexadecimal characters, "000B13AB". Hexlify will convert the binary string to hexadecimal characters, unhexlify will convert the hexadecimal characters to a binary string. If you want to add a value to the binary string, just do `'\x00' + unhexlify(StringToAppend)`.